# Table using siunitx number alignment affecting rows without numbers

Tags: tables, siunitx

I'm having trouble with this table:

[image]

As you can see, the headings of three of columns are not right. In terms of the rest of the table contents:

- `A` - this column is fine.
- `mathcal{B}` - the numbers aren't centered with regard to the column width.
- `mathcal{C}` - this column looks fine.
- `alpha` - is there any way to make these numbers centered in the column? I realise its tricky because of the minus sign and some numbers are longer than others. I'm not sure the best way to format this.

Any advice would be greatly appretiated.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all = true, detect-family = true} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table}
\label{table1}
\sisetup{
table-number-alignment = center,
}
\begin{tabular}{ l | S | S | S }
A & $\mathcal{B}$ (\si{\cm}) & $\mathcal{C}$ (\si{\cm}) & $\alpha$ (\si{\degree})  \\ 
\hline
$a$ & 5.1  & -2.8 & -20  \\
$b$ & 5.6  & -1.0 & -5\\
$c$ & 5.5 & 1.0 & 13 \\
$d$ & 4.8 & 2.8  & 33 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The non-numeric entries in a `S` column (e.g. column heads) should be enclosed in braces.

Comment: With your code you should have recieved an error like `! siunitx error: "invalid-number"
!
! Invalid numerical input '('.`. Generally, do not rely on the output that is generated by a code that also throws an error.